# Prepending regex matched test to all links in a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

Let's say I have a string $str like this:

```
aaa
<a href="link.php?x=banana">text 1</a>
bbb
<a href="different_url.php">text 2</a>
ccc
<a href="link.php?x=orange">text 3</a>
ddd
```

I want to make it so that all links that have link.php in them will have the x value prepended to them so for example:

```
aaa
banana <a href="link.php?x=banana">text 1</a>
bbb
<a href="different_url.php">text 2</a>
ccc
orange <a href="link.php?x=orange">text 3</a>
ddd
```

I'm trying to do this using preg_replace but I don't seem to be able to build my regex up properly:

```
$str = preg_replace('/<a (.*?)link.php(.*?)<\/a>/', '$2 <a $1link.php$2<\/a>', $str);
```

Of course this doesn't work. I'm a bit lost as to how to build this, since I want it to contain the entire original string, plus a subset.

What is the simplest way to do this? For future reference, what is this kind of operation even called?

Comment: Show your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using DOMDocument. You can easily insert something before a node with the `DOMNode::insertBefore` method.

```
$html = <<<'EOD'
aaa
<a href="link.php?x=banana">text 1</a>
bbb
<a href="different_url.php">text 2</a>
ccc
<a href="link.php?x=orange">text 3</a>
ddd
EOD;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div id="root">' . $html . '</div>');
$nodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($nodeList as $link) {
    $query = parse_url($link->getAttribute('href'), PHP_URL_QUERY);
    if ( !$query ) continue;
    parse_str($query, $arr);
    if ( isset($arr['x']) )
        $link->parentNode->insertBefore($dom->createTextNode($arr['x'] . ' '), $link);
}

$result = '';

foreach($dom->getElementById('root')->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $result .= $dom->saveHTML($childNode);
}

echo $result;
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/99tkc)

`DOMDocument` needs a root element to be able to build the DOM tree. Since you are dealing with a part of an html document and not a whole html document, you need to add a dummy root element `<div id="root">...</div>` and at the end to extract all the children of this root element.

Comment: I get empty on the last foreach getElementById('root')->childNodes though, but I see the other loops working. Thanks for the advice!